# mistake on return statement

Tags: java

Hi guys can someone correct my mistake?
The error is on the second line I try to put a void method which converts an integer

```
Integer g=Integer.valueOf(this.jTextField1.getText()).intValue();
Integer g=Integer.valueOf(this.jTextField1.getText()).intValue();
this.jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(this.convert(g)));
```

---

Hi guys can someone correct my mistake?
return does not work

```
public String convert(Integer number1) {
    Integer [] tab = new Integer[4]; 

    int i=tab.length-1;
    do {
        tab[i]=number1%10; 
        number1=number1/10;
        i--;
    } while(number1!=0);
    for(int g=0;g<=tab.length-1;g++) {
        if(tab[g]!=null){
            String f= String.format("%4s",Integer.toBinaryString(tab[g])).replace(' ', '0');
            return f;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and provide some more context.

Comment: You need to offer us more code than this. Where is your `convert` method declaration?

Comment: You can provide a runnable sample code with sample data.

Comment: You don't post enough pertinent code, you haven't looked at how to format your code for this site, you haven't posted your *complete* error message. Please help us help you.

Comment: So convert is a void method. Don't use a void method if you want a method to return something.

Comment: How about this: `this.jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(g));`

Comment: the method convert is worked i tried it on main  so i try only to convert the number and put it on jtextfield

Comment: I hope `convert()` is not a static method. Because `this` can not be used in a static context.

Comment: It's not working in a way that is helpful here. A void method returns nothing, and so it will give you no String or number. Why are you not showing the convert method?? Voting to close this question unless it's improved.

Comment: public void convert(Integer number1){ Integer [] tab = new Integer[4]; int i=tab.length-1; do{ tab[i]=number1%10; number1=number1/10; i--; }while(number1!=0); for(int g=0;g<=tab.length-1;g++){ if(tab[g]!=null){ System.out.print( String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(tab[g])).replace(' ', '0')); } } }

Answer (score 2):

My guess, your convert method is printing out a result but not returning a result:

```
public void convert(int number) {
    // do something to the number, creating theConvertedNumber
    System.out.println(theConvertedNumber);
}
```

This is worthless to you since you want to place the converted number into a JTextField, and you can't do this if the method returns nothing. Instead have it return the converted number:

```
public int convert(int number) {
    // do something to the number, creating theConvertedNumber
    return theConvertedNumber;
}
```

Regarding your latest code, you've got your return statement buried within an `if` block, and the compiler sees this.  So what happens if the if condition is false? The method that should return a String will then not have a viable way of returning anything. You must either take the return statement out of the if, and perhaps place it at the end, or give the if block an else block that also has a return statement.

Comment: public void convert(Integer number1){
   Integer [] tab = new Integer[4]; 
                 
 int i=tab.length-1;
   do{  
   tab[i]=number1%10; 
    number1=number1/10;
    i--;
   }while(number1!=0);
  for(int g=0;g<=tab.length-1;g++){
   if(tab[g]!=null){
   System.out.print( String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(tab[g])).replace(' ', '0'));
   
  } 

 }

 }

Comment: so your issue is as hovercraft full of eels says its because you use a void method for convert. Change its type and that will solve your issue

Comment: yes i think this my error but when when i put the return because i  used return statement in if it  shows me an error

Comment: well edit your question show the new code and the new error and we can help

Comment: public String convertir(Integer nombre1){
   Integer [] tab = new Integer[4]; 
                 
 int i=tab.length-1;
   do{  
   tab[i]=nombre1%10; 
    nombre1=nombre1/10;
    i--;
   }while(nombre1!=0);
  for(int g=0;g<=tab.length-1;g++){
   if(tab[g]!=null){
   String f= String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(tab[g])).replace(' ', '0');
   return f;
  } 


 }

 }

Comment: @nounou: Please don't post code in comments unless it is very short since you cannot format code for readability in comments. Instead [edit your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34043680/edit) (please click on this link), and add your new code there and any additional information about your new code.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels :i dont understand you